# How to solve add a custom error 503 page html on ubuntu apache2 using it with mod_jk and virtual host redirecting to tomcat

Tags: html, tomcat, ubuntu, apache2, errordocument

I tried all I found at apache documentation and other sugestions found at stackoverflow and blogs.
When I add the folloowing line to any configuration file like `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`:

`ErrorDocument 503 "This is an error msg"` or even an html message 
`ErrorDocument 503 "<h1> This is an error message </h1>`
or an external url redirect `ErrorDocument 503 http://www.google.com` it works.

But when I try an internal redirect like `ErrorDocument 503 /ERROR_503.html`
or `ErrorDocument 503 /error/ERROR_503.html` I get the default message with last line:

Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried to put the html error page at the DocumentRoot `var/www`, at `var/www/error`.
Try to uncomment all the file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages` that sets all errors to custom pages with internationalization that are at `/usr/share/apache2/error`. 
And as the messages inside this files are the same as the default, the line

Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
is not shown anymore. But if I change the line

```
`ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var`
```

at the localized-error-pages file to a new html placed at the same page, the error is back
and the page is not shown. If I edit the file `HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var` nothing change at the browser message too.

Some more information: I'm using apache2 just to redirect all request on port 80 to tomcat at port 8089 via an worker. My configuration files are https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1105054/apache.zip

Answer (score 7):

This took me way tooo long (partially due to spelling), but I thought I'd post my whole virtual host file since it might be useful.

You'll want to make sure you've specified a DocumentRoot, and that you do the `ProxyPass /file.html !` before your main `ProxyPass /`.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    #ProxyPreserveHost On

    <IfModule env_module>
         # Fake SSL if Loadbalancer does SSL-Offload 
         SetEnvIf Front-End-Https "^on$" HTTPS=on
    </IfModule>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile file
    SSLCertificateChainFile file

    ProxyPass /maintenance-message.html !
    ProxyPass /maintance-message_files !
    ProxyPass / "ajp://localhost:8009/"
    ProxyPassReverse / "ajp://localhost:8009/"
    ServerName server.something.com:443
    ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance-message.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: After hours of  searching and finding nothing! Thanks! I was missing ProxyPass /maintenance-message.html !. Still dont know what the '!' does but who cares?! it works!

Comment: If I remember correctly, it will exclude the `maintenance-message.html` file from being proxied and will instead serve it from `/var/www/html`.  (So the `!` inverts the command to say don't ProxyPass this file or folder.)

Comment: Yes I figured it out eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I just added this **ProxyPass** line to my virtualserver config:

```
ProxyPass /serverError.html !
ErrorDocument 503 /serverError.html
```

That tells the proxy to go to the DocumentRoot and search for the error page.

Also you may find useful this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019667

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue too and after deep searching I found here the best (and only?) solution from @Loren.

Worked after setting `ProxyPass /file.html !` before the main `ProxyPass /` and NOT after.
Also, DocumentRoot is needed as well.